# Appending a document line by line to a list

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, split, strip

I am trying to get each word in the text document "Payments" into a list. For each line of "Payments", I want it within a list in `myList`, so it would look something like this:

```
myList = [['E1234','12/09/14','440','A','0']['E3431','10/01/12','320','N','120']['E0987','04/12/16','342','A','137']]
```

I need to use `.split()` and `.strip()` in order to remove individual words from the commas and to remove the invisible next line space at the end of every line. This is my code that I have written so far:

```
myFile = open("Payments.txt")
myList = []
for line in myFile:
    print(line.strip())
    myList.append(line.strip())
myFile.close()
print(myList)
```

The program does work, but not in the way I was intending it to work. The program returned the following:

```
E1234,12/09/14,440,A,0
E3431,10/01/12,320,N,120
E0987,04/12/16,342,A,137
E5322,05/04/02,503,A,320
E9422,26/11/16,124,N,0
E7382,31/03/11,414,A,235
['E1234,12/09/14,440,A,0', 'E3431,10/01/12,320,N,120', 'E0987,04/12/16,342,A,137', 'E5322,05/04/02,503,A,320', 'E9422,26/11/16,124,N,0', 'E7382,31/03/11,414,A,235']
```

It has appended the document into `myList`, but it hasn't put each line into its' own list within `myList` and the line is a whole string, not individual strings, separated by a comma.

I did try adding `.split(',')` at the end of `for line in myFile:`, but it displayed an error message:

```
AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'split'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `.split()` on each `line`:

```
myList = []
for line in myFile:
    print(line.strip())
    myList.append(line.strip().split(","))
```

Or, in one line using a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
myList = [line.strip().split(",") for line in myFile]
```

Or, you can also use a [`csv` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html):

```
import csv

with open("Payments.txt") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    myList = list(reader)

print(myList)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do everything you ask for - getting a list of lines from an open file, stripping each line, and splitting by `,` - all in a single line:

```
myList = map(lambda line: line.strip().split(","), myFile.readlines())
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your approach is that you didn't split the lines after you read them.

As a more pythonic way, you better to open your file with `csv` module that splits the lines with a specified delimiter, and returns an iterable of split lines.

```
import csv
with open("Payments.txt") as myFile:
   spam_reader = csv.reader(myFile, delimiter=',')
   print (list(spam_reader))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
myList = []
for line in myFile:
    myList.append(line.strip().split(sep=','))
myFile.close()
print(myList)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the `.split()` function in each `line.strip()`, as follows:

```
myFile = open("Payments.txt")

myList = []

for line in myFile:
    print(line.strip())
    myList.append(line.strip().split(","))

myFile.close()
print(myList)
```

The result will be the one you're requesting:

```
>>>[['E1234','12/09/14','440','A','0']['E3431','10/01/12','320','N','120']['E0987','04/12/16','342','A','137']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
from pprint import pprint 

with open("Payments.txt") as myFile:
    myList = []
    for line in myFile:
        columns = line.strip().split(', ')
        myList.append(columns)

pprint(myList)
```

Note the use of the *context manager* that automatically closes your file once you're done and the *pretty print* library that puts each item of your list on a different line. It makes it easier to read.

Answer (score -1):

You used `strip()` instead of `split()`. Here is your original code modified to work:

```
myFile = open("Payments.txt")
myList = []
for line in myFile:
    print(line.strip())
    myList.append(line.split()) // We use split here
myFile.close()
print(myList)
```